# Is the Grassmannian bundle projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $E$ a complex vector bundle of rank $n$ on $X$. Write $\mathbb G(k,E)$ for the fiber bundle whose fibers are the Grassmannians $\mathbb G(k,E_x)$ where $E_x$ is a fiber of $E$ at $x$. I managed to show that $\mathbb G(k,E)$ is a smooth complete variety ; to show properness it suffices to show that the morphism $\mathbb G(k,E) \to X$ is proper since $X$ is projective, and since properness is local on the base it suffices to check on a trivializing neighborhood $U$ for $E$, so that
$$
\mathbb G(k,E|_U) \simeq U \times \mathbb G(k, \mathbb C^n)
$$ is an isomorphism of $U$-schemes and $U \times \mathbb G(k, \mathbb C^n) \to U$ is proper since $\mathbb G(k, \mathbb C^n)$ is projective and this is a base extension.

How do I show that $\mathbb G(k,E)$ is projective? It seems to be assumed in a paper I am reading and I didn't believe it at first because I thought that the twists in the bundle $E$ could prevent the existence of an embedding (i.e. the existence of a very ample invertible sheaf). Any ideas?

Comment: Letting $\pi:G\to X$ to be the Grassmannian, it comes equipped with an exact sequence $0\to S\to \pi^*E\to Q\to 0$, where $Q$ is a rank $k$ vector bundle on $G$. Then, one checks that $\pi^*L\otimes \Lambda^k Q$ is an ample bundle on $G$, where $L$ is any ample line bundle on $X$.

Comment: @Mohan : Sorry, but can you elaborate? I have no idea how to derive any of your claims. How do you construct $S$ and $Q$? How does "one check" your last claim? Still, your comment makes me happy because someone believes the Grassmannian bundle is indeed projective! Feel free to elaborate into an answer.

Comment: @Mohan : Is it possible that $S$ is the tautological bundle and $Q$ has rank $n-k$, not $k$? So that I take $\wedge^{n-k}Q$ instead? I don't know how to check ampleness though... I don't know if the results in Hartshorne suffice.

Comment: Grothendieck told us to take $Q$ to be the tautological quotient bundle, its behaviour is superior than taking subbundles. Here is a general fact: Let $f:S\to T$ be a projective morphism, $L$ ample on $T$ and $M$ a relatively ample line bundle on $S$. Then $f^*L\otimes M$ is ample on $S$.

Comment: @Mohan : Good thing he told you, 'cause he didn't tell me yet! (I didn't read much EGA so far). Do you mean that the morphism $\pi : G \to X$ is projective? If I knew this, I wouldn't have to deal with finding an ample sheaf... where would you look up the fact that $\pi^* L \otimes \Lambda^k Q$ is ample?

Comment: EGA of course. Just kidding. Any book which deals with relative Grassmannian should do these, especially, if they do the universal property of Grassmannian, rest is quite easy.

Comment: @Mohan : I'm one of these persons that doesn't mind reading EGA. Thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patrick,

May be without checking all the details, here is how it is done. I always think of rank $k$ quotients. Then, $G(k,E)$ and $G(k,E\otimes L)$ are naturally isomorphic for any line bundle $L$ on $X$. So, we may twist $E$ sufficiently and assume that $E$ is globally generated and so we have a surjection, $F=\mathcal{O}_X^N\to E$. From this, any rank $k$ quotient of $E$ is a rank $k$ quotient of $F$ and thus we get a closed embedding $G(k,E)\subset G(k,F)$. But, $G(k,F)=X\times G(k,N)$ and thus it is projective, if you knew that the usual Grassmannian (over a field) $G(k,N)$ is.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful answer. +1 :)